# Remove enclosing / surrounding tag in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Basically I'm looking for the WebStorm/IntelliJ shortcut "Ctrl+Shift+Del" which opens a picker where I can choose which surrounding tag to delete (defaulting to the first one, i.e. the direct parent tag of the cursor position).

There is "Emmet: Remove Tag" but that removes the tag my cursor is at. I want to remove the tag that surrounds this tag.

In other words, something like "Emmet: Unwrap", but that doesn't seem to exist in VSCode

Comment: then move your cursor to the surrounding tag and use `Emmet: Remove Tag`

Comment: Yeah that's the closest to what I'm looking for, and it works, but is a bit more cumbersome. In some situations, the Unwrap shortcut from IntelliJ is just more convenient and faster.

Comment: you can create a combo command with `runCommands` and move to the enclosing tag before removing, but then you don't have feedback which tag will be removed, or bind a key combo to `move to enclosing tag` and another for the `remove tag`